# Find largest value of integer in repeating string

Tags: vim, search

I have a script log file that looks a bit like this:

```
2012-9-16
Did something
Did 345 things
Script time: 244 seconds

2012-9-17
Did yet something
Did another thing 23 times
Script time: 352 seconds

2012-9-18
Did something special for 34 seconds 51 times
Did nothing at all
Script time: 122 seconds
```

I would like to find the largest value of `N` in the lines `Script time: N seconds`. However, I need to keep the context, so simply removing all lines that don't contain `Script time` in them is not a viable solution.

Currently, I am grepping for lines with `Script time`, then sorting those to find the highest value, then going back to the original file and searching for that value. However, if there is a more straightforward way then I would love to know.

This is on Vim 7.3 on a recent CentOS. I would prefer to remain in VIM if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with this VIM function:

```
function Find()
    execute "g!/Script/d"
    execute "sort"
    normal G
    normal 0v$"ay
    normal u
    execute "call search('".@a."')"
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can use a shell command in vim, but this would be my solution...little bit hacky:

```
cat test.txt | sed ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n\n/###/g" | sed ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g" | sed "s/###/\n/g" | sort "-nrt:" -k2 | head -1
```

Soooo...short explanation:

```
cat test.txt                  # Can be omitted as sed does also accept files,
                              # but I like it for readability
sed ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n\n/###/g"  # Replace the double-newlines with a placeholder
sed ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g"      # Replace all newlines with a space
sed "s/###/\n/g"              # Replace all placeholders with a newline
sort "-nrt:" -k2              # Sort numeric, reverse, use the :  as delimiter and
                              # use the second field for sorting
head -1                       # Give us only the first line
```

The `sed` is taken [from this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n).

Comment: Thank you, that is an interesting one-liner! However, it does only return the line but not the context, which can actually be gotten quite simply: `cat t | grep "Script time:" | sort -r | head -n 1`. As mentioned in the OP, I'm looking to add context (the associated log entry) to that!

Comment: @dotancohen: Huh? This returns the whole 4-line block in one line (sorry for that)...at least it did on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `awk`:

```
awk -vRS='' 'max<$(NF-1){max=$(NF-1);tmp=$0};END{print tmp}' input.txt
```

Call `awk` in `vim`:

```
:%!awk ...
```